# Attribute default value is always being saved as an int

Tags: config

Following block in `generateColumnDefinition($config)` function in `DbHelper.php` class is always converting default value to int if it is a numeric value. A numeric value can be a float so this is causing an issue:

```
if (isset($config['default']) && (is_string($config['default']) || is_bool($config['default']) || is_numeric($config['default'])))
{
    if (is_string($config['default']) && !is_numeric($config['default']))
    {
        $def .= ' DEFAULT "'.$config['default'].'"';
    }
    else
    {
        $def .= ' DEFAULT '.(int)$config['default'];
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can override this method? Any help much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t override that method from a plugin, if you really think it should be changed I’d suggest to file a feature request.

As a workaround you could try to set a default manually before the attribute is stored to the database or before the value is used. If it’s for a custom field type you could look into utilizing [`prepValue`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/fieldtypes/IFieldType#prepValue-detail) or [`prepValueFromPost`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/fieldtypes/IFieldType#prepValueFromPost-detail) for example.

Comment: Thank you for your response @carlcs . I'm setting the value in the Field Type settings so `prepValueFromPost` won't apply to this and default value would already be set by the time `prepValue` will be called.

Comment: Do you need to set `default` at all? What I actually had in mind is that you could check in `prepValue` if the value is already set using `is_empty()` or something like that and if that’s the case set the default.

Comment: yeah thats what I did. Many thanks for your help!